# Como deshabilitar el botón maximizar y evitar que se redimensione la app en Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola Quiero bloquear que se cambie de tamaño mi ventana y que el botón maximizar este deshabilitado.

Este es mi código:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk() 



window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

Podrías intentar algo de la siguiente manera

```
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()

# esto remueve el botón maximizar
root.resizable(0,0)

root.mainloop()
```